# Replace NAs with random string from a list

Tags: r

I have a df with a variable (fruit) that has some NANs. I would like to replace the NANs only in this variable with a random string from a list (eg; apple, banana, peach, pear, strawberry).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. You set up your vector of possible fruits to select from, and then everywhere there is an `NA` in `df$fruit`, pick a random element from the possible fruit vector to overwrite it with:

```
randomFruits = c("apple", "banana", "peach", "pear", "strawberry")
df$fruit[is.na(df$fruit)] = randomFruits[sample(length(randomFruits), length(is.na(df$fruit)),replace=TRUE)]
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
randomFruits = c("apple", "banana", "peach", "pear", "strawberry")
df$fruit[is.na(df$fruit)] = sample(randomFruits, length(is.na(df$fruit)),replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Why do you need: sample(length(randomFruits)... instead of sample(randomFruits...     I thought the first argument of sample is the list of elements to be sampled.

Comment: @NeedMoreStatsHelp Thanks for the comment, I wrote that in a rather verbose way that could probably use some shortening. The way you propose of sampling the randomFruit vector directly makes a lot of sense and would be easier to read. The way I'm doing it, I sample the *indices* of the randomFruit vector, and pull those elements out of the vector itself with randomFruits[randomIndices], where everything inside the square brackets generates a vector of random indices of a particular length (rather than the values of those indices themselves).

Comment: thank you again for your help! I'm clearly new to R and I appreciate it. If you don't mind, a follow-up question. I tried the code:   df$fruit[is.na(df$fruit)] = randomFruits[sample(randomFruits, length(is.na(df$fruit)),replace=TRUE)]   but that didn't result in any replacement. 1) Any idea why?  2) What I'm confused about your solution is that I would think the:  length(randomFruits)  portion would tell sample to pick a number 1:5 given as opposed to tell it to look at the index position. What is going on to tell it to use index positions?

Comment: @NeedMoreStatsHelp I edited the answer to include the shorter version. Your code is sampling the *values* of the random fruits and then tries to get the elements of the random fruit vector with those *names*, but the random fruit vector doesn't have element names, so it returns NA. In my first version, I'm getting random numeric indices 1:5, and then using the outermost randomFruits[indices] to select elements with those indices. c("A","B","C")[c(1,1,3,2)] will return c("A","A","C","B"), but c("A","B","C")[c("apple","orange")] will return NAs.

Comment: @NeedMoreStatsHelp Your code would work if the random fruit vector could be referenced by name instead of index. If you set names(randomFruit) = randomFruit, you could get the first element of the randomFruit vector with either randomFruit[1] or randomFruit["apple"], but without setting the names of the vector, the second approach  won't work.

Comment: that makes complete sense now. Thank you!